# NXC communication through USB

Tags: linux, usb, nxt, nxc

How would you send data through the USB port and receive the data in my Linux machine?

```
task main ()
{
byte data[2] = {1,2};
while (1)
{
  Wait(1000);
  SetUSBOutputBuffer(0, 2, data);
}
}
```

Compiled it with:

```
nbc -d -Z2 usb.nxc
```

dmesg:

```
usb 2-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
```

Now how do I get the "data" what was sent by the NXT?How would I write a Linux program in C that would read the USB buffer?

Comment: Fantom SDK? I've never done it before, though. Maybe even look at the source for simple programs that have Computer<->USB<->NXT communication.

Comment: @muntoo Where is the link for the Fantom SDK?

Comment: I think it's the first "Software Developer Kit" on [this page](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/support/files/Advanced.aspx).

Comment: An Arch and Haskell user! So hipster! :P Do you use xmonad?

Answer (score 1):

The Fantom SDK doesn't support Linux. Instead, use libnxt. The one in the Debian repositories is still being maintained.